# Long text in twitter bootstrap nav-list crosses container border

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi guys im making a website with Bootstrap and CodeIgniter, now im designing the news page with 2 side nav-list and  I have a problem. 
When I put a long text on the nav-list, the text comes out. Please help me.

```
<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2"></div>

    <div class="span8"></div>

    <div class="span2">

        <ul class="nav nav-list well">
            <div class="row-fluid">
            <li class="nav-header">Suggested Users</li>

            <li class="span12">
                <div class="span4">
                    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/0YJjVnH.gif" alt="User suggested">
                </div>
                <div class="span8">
                    <a href="#" style="font-size: 12px;">Aezir ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss</a>
                    <button class="btn btn-mini btn-info pull-right">Follow</button>
                    <br>
                    <strong><small class="pull-right" style="font-size: 9px;">1024 followers</small></strong>
                </div>
            </li>
            </div>
        </ul> 

    </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: [Problem screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/wxt8XE0.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the length of the word overflowing the container, you can somewhat fix this by adding something like `word-wrap: break-word;` to that `a` tag to break the text that overflows out of the container but what I would suggest is to just add enough room for long words around that space. That way you won't have to force the words to break into a new line.